# Issue in hiding TabBar in the pushed ViewController, TabBar appearing after some delay

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios11

TabBar is not hiding in the pushed ViewController, I used the below code to hide the tabBar,

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
                or
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

But still tabBar appears after some delay. if anyone faced this kind of issue, and able to fix it. your answer will be greatly helpful.

[image]

I did this as well in the storyBoard.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to hide the tabor on a particular controller you can do :

`controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I had done all the ways to hide the tabBar including your answer. TabBar will be hidden when I enter to the screen. but after some time it is re-appearing. this is the issue I am facing.

Comment: `controller` is referencing the one you push, not the tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBarController` have property `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` so you have to set `true` on the controller you are going to push.

For example:

```
    //pushedVC - VC you try to push(the one where you don't want to show TabBar)
    pushedVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    navigationController?.pushViewController(pushedVC, animated: true)
```

**OR**

Set this in `Storyboard`

[image]

> [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed)

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for the answer. I had done all the ways to hide the tabBar including your answer. TabBar will be hidden when I enter to the screen. but after some time it is re-appearing. this is the issue I am facing.

Comment: @RamprasadA Take a look at an updated answer. You should set it property to `ViewController` you trying to push. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RamprasadA where you doing this action `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`, in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @RamprasadA try to check `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden` value inside `viewDidAppear` using breakpoint. I'm almost sure it's changing somewhere. Cause this flow looking weird.

Comment: I am setting it in only one place, no where in the screen I am setting the tabBar isHidden property. This issue is troubling a lot.

Comment: @RamprasadA last what I can advice it's to try setting `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden` inside of `viewDidAppear`. But it's not a solution, just kind of hotfix.

Comment: Didn't work setting tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden, I presented a new navigation bar with the vc as root controller.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is just select the "Hide bottom bar on push" property of ViewController for which you want to hide the Bar. Please check the screen shot. Note: Programetically writing "self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true" sometimes doesn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Hi Naresh, I did this, but didn't work. the navigation bar appears still.

Comment: Navigation bar or TabBar ?

Comment: tabBar. not navigationBar